# git commit pushed to branch on remote ok but cannot be pulled to another developer's repo

Tags: git, branch, shared

We have a shared "development" repo on a central server, with different branches, call them v4, v5, v6

A developer ("Alice") has made a commit to v6 and everything looks good. I have a post-receive hook which has picked up all the relevant details, the continuous integration server can clone the repo and check out this commit and work on it - all is great.

However, when I checkout v6 in my personal copy and git pull, I don't get the commit "Alice" made at all. It does not show up in the log or get pulled to my machine at all.

When I browse the repo via cgit, the commit does not show up in the "logs" - but I can see the commit if I construct the viewing URL from the SHA and branch.

It's like Alice has pushed to an invisible parallel v6 branch in the central (bare) repo. How do I make this invisible branch reveal itself?

So what could have happened? A few hours before Alice did her commit, I deleted the v6 branch on the central repo, using the `git push origin :v6` command. v6 was empty and based on the original master, but I wanted it to derive from the latest v5 work instead. To this end I then checked out v5, did a git pull and then checked this out to v6.  I then pushed this v6 to the shared repo.

So it looks like my delete didn't work, and somehow Alice pushed to v6 but not the v6 that git thinks is v6.

My fix? Modify the refs/heads/Release_6 on the bare repo to contain the SHA of Alice's commit.

But is that the right thing to do? How does git maintain or permit a shadow branch without seriously complaining?  Git isn't complaining in my repo or Alice's..

ANSWERED:
Looks like the bare repo refs/heads/v6 got SNAFU'd by my clumsy rebase attempt. After writing the SHA of Alice's commit to the bare repo refs/heads/v6, everything appears at it should do.

## POST_MORTEM analysis.

The server "bare" repo was in fact cloned from some original work (using --bare).  The original repo had v4, v5, v6.

There was a script running at the weekend which did a `git fetch origin +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*`on the bare repo whcch, I guess, because of the "+" modifier, handily overwrote the "new" v6 that we had created with the "legacy" v6 from the original repo.

This explains why the v6 work seemed to work, then over the weekend disappeared.

No git's fault, quite clearly a mistake of my own making.  Time to sit on the naughty step.

Comment: _the server can check out this commit and work on it  ..._ So is the server a bare repo or not?

Comment: yes - the server repo is bare - it's used for collaboration. the comment you refer to relates to our integration server which clones the bare to get the latest commits.

Answer (score 0):

You have not given all the commands I suspect but here is how it looks to me.

You, Alice and 'origin' (the central repository) all have a v6 branch. These will be called in your repository v6, alice/v6, origin/v6 (assuming you had a remote pointing at alices repository). You deleted the central one with your 'git push origin :v6'. That leaves you and alice with v6 branches (unless you also deleted your local branch with 'git branch -d v6' or did a 'git fetch origin --prune' following the push).

At this point there is no origin/v6. alice/v6 and your local v6 refer to the same commit. Alice does work and pushes to origin/v6 re-creating the branch with new work on top.

You now fetch which brings back origin/v6 locally. But unless you checkout v6 and do either git pull or git merge origin/v6 your local branch will not get updated to match origin/v6.

Your real problem here is you are planning to rebase v6 on current v5. If you want to do that you have to get all the developers involved to agree. If you had done this before Alice made her commit - should would quite rightly be very annoyed. Re-read the Git book sections on rebasing published branches and think about just merging new work from v65 into v6.

Comment: fair comment - I think there was a race condition between my clumsy rebase of v6 and Alice's checkout & commit. I've just written Alice's SHA to refs/heads/v6 and pointed HEAD to it.